# The float value becomes integer after assignment into np.array which is copy.deepcopy of another one in Pyhton

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to fill a np.array with coordinates. For this reason I make the copy of a known np.array to keep the right array size:

```
real_position = copy.deepcopy(self.param_coord)
```

After that I calculate the coordinates I'm interested in, for example x-value, and assign it to the newly created np.array:

```
real_position[0][0] = self.param_coord[0][0] + self.global_point[0]
```

If one calculates the right-hand side then it gives us the numpy.float64 number (in my case the number is 88.86093333333335), but if one outputs the `real_position[0][0]` value it turns out that it is exactly 88(numpy.int32). This was the cause of a systematic error in my calculations and I have already eliminated it simply by replacing `copy.deepcopy(self.param_coord)`  with `np.zeros((len(self.param_coord),len(self.param_coord[0])))`. But I have no idea why it happened so(apparently the problem is in the `copy.deepcopy` or in the some properties of np.array?) and would like to know the reason to avoide such problems in future.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you use `np.zeroes_like(self.param_coord, dtype=np.float64)`

Comment: JonasV - Thank you for advace with `dtype=np.float64` parameter. I went through all the code right down to the module where the corresponding class was defined. The default values was numbers without dots which was recognized as `numpy.int32` by np.array. When I pointed out `self.param_coord = np.array(param_coord, dtype=np.float64)` or simply the dot after the number the code began to work correctly. But what surprised me was that numpy automatically transforms float to int instead of doing vice versa procedure or, at least, give any warning/

Comment: A dot after a number makes it a `float`.  One float in the whole `np.array` input is enough to set the array `dtype`.  One string also sets it.  In assignment the dtype of the existing array does not change.  With your `int` dtype array, each assigned value is converted with a `int(12.232)` like action.  Assigning a complex value will raise an error, because `int(1+4j)` does.  `casting` is a big topic.